# rosrun or roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow,

Easy question does roslaunch just execute a set of rosrun or is it slightly different ? I couldn't find it in the doc...
I'm asking that because I'm under the impression that my node run slower when launch with a roslaunch then with a rosrun.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147321/rosrun-or-roslaunch/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-04-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [henriquejsfj](https://answers.ros.org/users/33316/henriquejsfj/) on 2018-01-16**:
I had the same impression, I made a .launch file to calibrate camera, but It were very slower. When I run the same nodes using rosrun for each node it is really faster. But I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Startup might be slower, I think it should not be slower after roslaunch and all created processes have are detached and up. I am not into the roslaunch implementation but I have not had this impression so far. You can use `rosnode ping /your_node` or if your node publishes anything you can use `rostopic hz /your_topic` (preferred) in order to "verify" your impression...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1